# How to organize the interaction between a corda node and a GlassFish java web server?

Tags: java, glassfish, corda

I use the corda platform and want to use the glassfish server, tell me how to organize the interaction of the corda node and the GlassFish java web server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the Spring Webserver example [here](https://github.com/corda/samples) for an example of a Spring Boot webserver that interacts with a Corda node. The design will be similar for a GlassFish webserver.

**Communicating with the node:**

The key file is https://github.com/corda/samples/blob/release-V3/spring-webserver/src/main/kotlin/net/corda/server/NodeRPCConnection.kt. Here, we create a long-lived `CordaRPCClient` instance. The webserver's controllers use this client to send messages to and from the node, as shown here: https://github.com/corda/samples/blob/release-V3/spring-webserver/src/main/kotlin/net/corda/server/controllers/StandardController.kt.

**Dependencies:**

The webserver requires dependencies on Corda itself (for the core classes and the RPC client classes). See https://github.com/corda/samples/blob/release-V3/spring-webserver/build.gradle#L47. The webserver will also require dependencies on any CorDapps that contain classes that will be used by the controllers. For example, if you have a controller with an endpoint that extracts `IOUState`s from the vault, then the `IOUCorDapp` will be a dependency of your webserver.